# failed to reconnect to your remote session

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10, remote-desktop-services, rds

When I try to connect I get a black screen for a minute and then I get this message

> failed to reconnect to your remote session please try to connect again

I ping it and it's fine network is working properly, I'm out of ideas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using a public IP with a port and it wasn't working today (it worked fine yesterday), but **using a local IP seems to work.**

**if you have other solutions please post it...**

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in one of the answers, rebooting definitely helps. But if you dont wanna do that, try close all existing remote desktop windows IF you are having this issue and make sure there are no more remaining rdp processes in task manager.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced exact same behavior, and in my case it was a low memory issue. I saw a antivirus eat up huge memory and there wasn't any more memory available in computer to open the RDP Connection. I simply restarted to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On your remote windows system, Click Start button followed by Run.
Type:
mstsc /console
Now try the authentication.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Windows is still warming up. Try again after sometime, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but It was on, I was in the same room as the desktop.

Comment: When I said warming up, it means a few background services are still not up and running so wait for them to finish.